# how to add a map to arraylist, by value

Tags: java, arraylist, addition

I am trying to add an object of class Document to an arraylist in a loop.
the problem is that every time the object changes, the prevous contents of the list changes too

here's my Document class:

```
public class Document {
    public Map<String, Double> tokens;
    public String category;    
}
```

and I have the list dataset:

```
List<Document> dataset = new ArrayList<Document>();
```

I read all the tokens of a document from a file to a map named counts. then do as follows

```
doc = new Document();
doc.tokens = counts;
doc.category=sampleCategory;
dataset.add(doc);

counts.clear();
```

but every time i read a new doc, the contents of dataset changes to the values of new doc.
So how can I add the doc by value, not by reference?

Comment: Are you asking how to make a copy of a `Document` object?

Comment: In Java you cannot pass an object by value. You pass the object **reference** by value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're adding the same 'counts' object to all of your Document instances. Instead of `counts.clear()`, assign counts to a new instance of the corresponding type:

```
counts = new HashMap<String, Double>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing the **same instances** for **counts** and **sampleCategory** everytime, so any modification will modify the rest.

You should create a new objects each time, and then assign into the **new Document**.